# Why having const and non-const accessors?

Tags: c++, constants, getter

Why do the STL containers define const and non-const versions of accessors ?

What is the advantage of defining `const T& at(unsigned int i) const` and `T& at(unsigned int)` and not only the non-const version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same function with const and without - When and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825443/same-function-with-const-and-without-when-and-why)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you wouldn't be able to call `at` on a `const` vector object.

If you only had the non-`const` version, the following:

```
const std::vector<int> x(10);
x.at(0);
```

would not compile. Having the `const` version makes this possible, and at the same time prevents you from actually changing what `at` returns - which is by contract, since the vector is `const`.

The non-`const` version can be called on a non-`const` object and allows you to modify the returned element, which is also valid because the vector isn't const.

```
const std::vector<int> x(10);
      std::vector<int> y(10);

int z = x.at(0);          //calls const version - is valid
x.at(0) = 10;             //calls const version, returns const reference, invalid

z = y.at(0);              //calls non-const version - is valid
y.at(0) = 10;             //calls non-const version, returns non-const reference
                          //is valid
```