# operator[] overloading C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

So, I have to write two versions of the bracket operator for a class that I am writing.

Details:
The class has a private variable that is an array of strings.
The versions of operator[] differ in that one must be const, and the other not

I'm a little unsure how these two versions actually differ, and how when called, they will be able to be differentiated.

The one I currently have written

```
string& MyClass::operator[](unsigned int index);
```

simply returns the string at the index.

My question is, what is the point of having one const and one non-const? And how will they differ from each other?

EDIT:
Since I have to write these, will the code within each function be identical?

Comment: Read all the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479548/why-having-const-and-non-const-accessors

Comment: @Salgar Handling (wrapped) containers might need some additional considerations ...

Answer (score 3):

The correct overloaded versions are:

1. Access non const MyClass instance

   `std::string& MyClass::operator[](unsigned int index);`
2. Access const or temp MyClass instance

   `const std::string& MyClass::operator[](unsigned int index) const;`

The latter guarantees that access through a constant instance reference won't allow to modify the returned `std::string` reference, but to return a result though.

Implementation might need to consider that you could at least add new (default) string values to your container for currently unknown index values, and you'll need to decide how to handle unknown index values for `const` access (return empty string, throw exception, etc.).